# 0-1 Knapsack problem - implementation

Tags: algorithm, rust, knapsack-problem

Given a set of items with a weight and a value, this problem gives the subset of items which maximize value so that their combined weights is less or equal than a given maximum weight. This solution runs in \$O(w\cdot n)\$ where \$n\$ is the number of items and \$w\$ is the max weight.

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Item {
    value: usize,
    weight: usize,
}

impl Item {

    fn new(pvalue: usize, pweight: usize) -> Item { 
        Item { value: pvalue, weight: pweight }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Info {
    ks_value: usize,
    added_weight: usize,
    included: bool,
}

impl Info {
    fn new(pks_value: usize, padded_weight: usize, pincluded: bool) -> Info{
        Info {
            ks_value: pks_value,
            added_weight: padded_weight,
            included: pincluded,
        }  
    }
}

impl std::cmp::Ord for Info {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Info) -> std::cmp::Ordering {
        self.ks_value.cmp(&other.ks_value)
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for Info {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Info) -> Option<std::cmp::Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}

impl PartialEq for Info {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Info) -> bool {
        self.ks_value == other.ks_value
    }
}

impl Eq for Info {}

fn _0_1_knapsack_items<'a>(items: &'a[Item], max_weight: usize, subproblems: &[Vec<Info>]) -> Vec<&'a Item>{
        (1..items.len() + 1).rev()
        .scan(max_weight, |w, i| {
                let sub    = &subproblems[i][*w];
                let result = (i, sub.included);
                *w -= sub.added_weight;
                Some(result)
        })
        .filter(|&(_, inc)| inc)
        .take_while(|&(i, _)| i > 0)
        .map(|(i, _)| &items[i - 1])
        .collect::<Vec<&Item>>()
}

fn _0_1_knapsack<'a>(items: &'a [Item], max_weight: usize) -> Vec<&'a Item>{
    let mut subproblems = vec! [ vec! [ Info::new(0, 0, false);
                                       max_weight + 1 ]; 
                                 items.len() + 1 ];
    for i in 0..items.len() {
        for w in 0..max_weight + 1 { 
            let w_i      = items[i].weight;
            let exc_cost = subproblems[i][w].ks_value;
            subproblems[i + 1][w] = if  w < w_i {
                Info::new(exc_cost, 0, false)
            } 
            else {
                let inc_cost = subproblems[i][w - w_i].ks_value 
                               + items[i].value;
                std::cmp::max(Info::new(exc_cost, 0, false), 
                              Info::new(inc_cost, w_i, true))     
            }
        }
    }
    _0_1_knapsack_items(items, max_weight, &subproblems)
}


fn main() {
    let items = [ Item::new(92, 23),  //1
                  Item::new(57, 31),  //1
                  Item::new(49, 29),  //1
                  Item::new(68, 44),  //1
                  Item::new(60, 53),  //0
                  Item::new(43, 38),  //1
                  Item::new(67, 63),  //0
                  Item::new(84, 85),  //0
                  Item::new(87, 89),  //0
                  Item::new(72, 82) ];//0

    for i in _0_1_knapsack(&items, 165){
        println!("{:?}", i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check out [Rustfmt](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustfmt).
2. There's a [Clippy](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy) warning for `zero_one_knapsack`: `explicit lifetimes given in parameter types where they could be elided`.
3. Don't prefix every parameter with `p`. There's no naming conflict and it adds confusion to everyone that tries to use the API. Especially for variables like `padded_weight`, where "padded" is another English word!
4. Introduce a `key` method to DRY up `Ord` / `PartialEq` / `Hash` implementations.
5. A leading `_` means that item is **unused** but must be present for some reason; don't call your methods that. Switch to words since identifiers can't start with numbers
6. Start iteration in `zero_one_knapsack_items` at 0. This simplifies the logic and shows that `take_while` can be removed.
7. This also leads to using `iter` and `enumerate` instead of operating on a range.
8. In turn, this leads to removing the need for indexing into `items`.
9. Remove the `result` temporary variable. It doesn't introduce a useful name and doesn't need to occur in a different temporal location.
10. There is a `filter_map` that does two operations in one, but I like the separation of `filter` and `map` here. You almost want a `scan_map`.
11. There's no need to specify type on `collect`; it's inferred from the return type of the function.
12. I'm not a fan of the truncated variable names. Computers don't care about long names, but humans do care about short names. This is especially true when there are overlapping meanings for prefixes like `inc` (`included` or `inclusive`).
13. Prefer iterating on a slice instead of on a range of numbers. If you *need* the number, use `enumerate`; this avoids out-of-bounds checking on each index operation.
14. Implement `Default` for your type if there's an appropriate value.
15. Import `Ord` and `max` to make that code a bit cleaner to read.

```
use std::cmp::{Ord, max};

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Item {
    value: usize,
    weight: usize,
}

impl Item {
    fn new(value: usize, weight: usize) -> Item {
        Item {
            value: value,
            weight: weight,
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Info {
    ks_value: usize,
    added_weight: usize,
    included: bool,
}

impl Info {
    fn new(ks_value: usize, added_weight: usize, included: bool) -> Info {
        Info {
            ks_value: ks_value,
            added_weight: added_weight,
            included: included,
        }
    }

    fn key(&self) -> usize {
        self.ks_value
    }
}

impl Ord for Info {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Info) -> std::cmp::Ordering {
        self.key().cmp(&other.key())
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for Info {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Info) -> Option<std::cmp::Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}

impl PartialEq for Info {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Info) -> bool {
        self.key() == other.key()
    }
}

impl Eq for Info {}

impl Default for Info {
    fn default() -> Info {
        Info::new(0, 0, false)
    }
}

fn zero_one_knapsack_items<'a>(items: &'a [Item],
                               max_weight: usize,
                               subproblems: &[Vec<Info>]) -> Vec<&'a Item>
{
    items.iter().enumerate()
        .rev()
        .scan(max_weight, |w, (i, item)| {
            let subproblem = &subproblems[i+1][*w];
            *w -= subproblem.added_weight;
            Some((item, subproblem.included))
        })
        .filter(|&(_, included)| included)
        .map(|(item, _)| item)
        .collect()
}

fn zero_one_knapsack(items: &[Item], max_weight: usize) -> Vec<&Item> {
    let mut subproblems = vec![vec![Info::default(); max_weight + 1]; items.len() + 1];

    for (i, item) in items.iter().enumerate() {
        for w in 0..max_weight + 1 {
            let w_i = item.weight;
            let exclusive_cost = subproblems[i][w].ks_value;
            subproblems[i + 1][w] = if w < w_i {
                Info::new(exclusive_cost, 0, false)
            } else {
                let inclusive_cost = subproblems[i][w - w_i].ks_value + item.value;
                max(Info::new(exclusive_cost, 0, false),
                    Info::new(inclusive_cost, w_i, true))
            }
        }
    }

    zero_one_knapsack_items(items, max_weight, &subproblems)
}

fn main() {
    let items = [Item::new(92, 23),  // 1
                 Item::new(57, 31),  // 1
                 Item::new(49, 29),  // 1
                 Item::new(68, 44),  // 1
                 Item::new(60, 53),  // 0
                 Item::new(43, 38),  // 1
                 Item::new(67, 63),  // 0
                 Item::new(84, 85),  // 0
                 Item::new(87, 89),  // 0
                 Item::new(72, 82)]; // 0

    for i in zero_one_knapsack(&items, 165) {
        println!("{:?}", i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like there should be a more iterator-focused version of `zero_one_knapsack`, but I'm not seeing it right now.

Comment: `take_while` wasn't needed in my version either, I probably change something and forgot to remove it, same with `result` local variable * facepalm *. As always that was a great review, thanks :).

Comment: @MAG oh, it's definitely not needed in the original version. I didn't *change* any external behavior (I hope). My point is that by rewriting the code as `i + 1 > 0` made it very obvious that it would always be true, seeing as how it was a `usize`.